# Trying to insert data into database table but nothing happens?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP, MYSQL, trying to add some sort of data to a table that i made in html and php code. my database is in phpmyadmin, it's just random list of things like office supplies and stuff. I'll provide the information of the table down below. Now i also made an insert where if you click on it you're lead to input fields where you can add or insert data to the database. I echo-ed what the result would be if the inserted data was to actually be inserted and if it didnt work what would pop up. By the way i am getting no errors whatsoever so i'm really not sure what the problem is. Also please bear with me my english is bad so i can't explain this properly. Here are the codes, there are 4 separate files:
here is the linking code to the database:

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$user ='mysql1_user';
$password ='ABCD1234';
$databasename ='mysqldb1';

$con= mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password, $databasename);
if(!$con){
    die("Wrong Entry for database". mysqli_connect_error());

}
else{
    //echo "Correct Entry";

}
?>
```

here is the main code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MYSQL</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <a href="f1.php?page=insert">INSERT</a><br><br><br>


<?php
@$v1=$_GET['page'];
if($v1=='insert'){ 
    $insertp = <<<t1
    Name: <input id="name">
    Quantity: <input id="qty">
    Type: <input id="type">
    Price: <input id="price">
    <button id="add">Add</button>
    <script>
    $("add").click(function(){
        $.post("insert.php", {
            name: $("#name").val(),
            qty: $("#qty").val(),
            type: $("#type").val(),
            price: $("#price").val(),

        },
        function(result){
            $("body").append(result);

        })


    })
    </script>

t1;
    echo $insertp;
}
else{
require "config/con1.php";
echo "<input type='search'><button id='search'>Search</button>";
$sql1="SELECT *FROM products 
-- WHERE name='Pen' ORDER BY price DESC  WHERE type='Office' AND price BETWEEN 10 and 700 ";

$result= mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
$value = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
echo "<table border=2>";
while($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>".$line ['name']. "</td><td>".$line["qty"]."</td><td>".$line['type']."</td><td>".$line['price']."</td><td><a href=edit.php?id=".$line['id']."><img src='pencil.png' width='50'></a></td><td><img src='delete.png' width='50' class='delete' id=".$line['id']."></td></tr>"; 
    }
    echo "</table>"; 
}
?>

<script>
$("#search").click(function(){
    var varval=$("input[type='search']").val();
    $.post("search.php", {vtext: varval}, function (value){
        $("table").html(value)

    })

})
    $(".delete").click(function(){
        var delid=$(this);
        $.post("delete.php", {deleteid:$(this).attr("id")}, function(result){
            $(delid).parent().parent().hide(2000)

        });

    })

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is where the inserting code is:

```
    <?php
require "config/con1.php";
$name=$_POST['name'];
$qty=$_POST['qty'];
$type=$_POST['type'];
$price=$_POST['price'];

$secure_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);
$secure_qty=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $qty);
$secure_type=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $type);
$secure_price=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $price);
$sql="INSERT INTO products(name, qty, type, price) VALUES ('$secure_name', '$secure_qty', $secure_type, $secure_price)";

if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    echo "One detail has been inserted into the database";

}
else{
    echo "Wrong ". mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: you checked for errors on one query, but not the other. You have some serious coding issues in that one.

Comment: You are missing a space in the SELECT statement. Should be one after the * .

Comment: alright so i added in the # for add as its an id, also the space after the asterisk and it;s working fine now, thank you!

Comment: Lesson?  Always make sure your web endpoints (php programs) accepting `.post()` operations are actually invoked, and contain the parameters you need.

Answer (score 1):

$(‘add’) should be $(‘#add’). If you want to bind an id you need to add #.

Answer (score -1):

Change your INSERT query to:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO products(name, qty, type, price) VALUES ('$secure_name', '$secure_qty', '$secure_type', '$secure_price')";
```